# Install Terraform on Kubuntu 22.10

Tags: software-installation, kubuntu, 22.10

I need help installing Terraform on Kubuntu 22.10 Kinetic.

There is no Kinetic(22.10) on Hashicorp [website](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/tutorials/aws-get-started/install-cli)

I do not want to use snapd version either because I am afraid it will not work properly.
I maybe wrong on *this*

Comment: Sorry about it. I figure it out. I went back to website and did manual install. PPA saying there no "kinetic" version for TerraForm

Answer (score 0):

I play dumb.

Instead let $(lsb_release -cs) run and fill with kinetic (22.10), that does not exists yet at hashicorp repo, i manually add jammy to force use packages from 20.04... and i got success install

```
echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/hashicorp-archive-keyring.gpg] \
    https://apt.releases.hashicorp.com $(lsb_release -cs) main" | \
    sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/hashicorp.list

echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/hashicorp-archive-keyring.gpg] \
    https://apt.releases.hashicorp.com jammy main" | \
    sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/hashicorp.list
```

Can this create problem i do not know? Yes!

Can i solve later? yes :)

```
desktop:~$ terraform --version
Terraform v1.3.5
on linux_amd64
```